# Why does my logo fail to load after logging into Rails App?

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-5

My logo loads on my RoR application locally. When I login however, it fails to load each time. If however, I redirect to the same page, it will load again. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.

The link to my project can be found here https://github.com/dlyons8/family-and-community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo cannot be loaded because your path is being changed after successfully logging in as an user. The Sessions controller will be redirect the user to `/users/:user_id`.

The affected `src` attribute in the `<img>` tag contains "logo.png" so the browser tries to fetch `/users/logo.png` which will not succeed.

You have two options:

**1) Change your logo as an asset.** This is commonly used pattern for resources and helps a lot later in deployment when you change the logo for example. Move `logo.png` to `app/assets/images` and in the [app/views/layouts/application.html.erb](https://github.com/dlyons8/family-and-community/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L15) use the `image_tag` helper:

```
<%= image_tag 'logo.png', alt: 'Logo' %>
```

In this way, you will always get the absolute path of your logo (`/assets/logo.png`) and don't have to worry about where is the user actually.

**2) Change the path** in the `<img>` tag to absolute path of the logo (`/logo.png`) and it will try to fetch the correct file.

The 2) solution would be easier, however I strongly recommend you to get in touch with the [Asset Pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) in Rails because it really helps a lot in handling static assets for your webpage.

Also, if you encounter a non-loading asset, always check the browser's console. In Google Chrome, you can reach it by simply pressing `F12` and switching to `Console` tab, there will be a red error message about what resource could not be loaded and why. The displayed full URL is often helps in these sneaky problems.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the images under assets/images folder

```
<%= image_tag ("/assets/ruby.jpeg") %>
```

change assets compile to true default it is false in **config/environments/development.rb**
config.assets.compile = true